# What is HeartBleed?

Tags: tls, heartbleed

Today when I woke up , I got a email from Godaddy that contain “A critical vulnerability with OpenSSL, known as 'The Heartbleed Bug' was recently announced that could potentially impact your server“

I don’t know what Heartbleed is. Please help me protect my server.

Comment: If you're already using GoDaddy it's not as if heartbleed could make your security situation all that much worse, but still...

Answer (score 0):

HeartBleed is a vulnerability in the heart beat extension of OpenSSL. Heart Beat extension works to keep alive a SSL session. But it accepts some user input which is not properly implemented for bound checks which is happened to be exploited in this scenario, causing memory leak in the OpenSSL servers upto 64K.